# FlashDevelop Actionscript 3 development environment inquiry

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flashdevelop

I'm puzzled by the FlashDevelop environment.  I'm working through the tutorial at:

http://prototyprally.com/making-games-in-actionscript-3-using-flashdevelop-part-1-the-setup/

I'm doing things exactly the way he describes.  However, once I add the class Enemy I am not able to establish communication between Main and Enemy.  Obviously I'm missing something basic, but I get compile time errors no matter what I do.

I'm using the latest version of FlashDevelop (4.5.2.5). How do I get two different files (both under the same package) to communicate with each other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I figured it out.  The import statement needs to be:

import com.grapefrukt.tutorial.supergame.enemies.Enemy

Looks like the size of the display in the tutorial chopped that off.

Comment: And I finally noticed the drag bar at the bottom of the code.  Sheesh- must be a slow learner...  :-)

Answer (score 0):

You instantiate 'Enemy' in 'Main.' Then you refer to it by its instance name.

So, for instance inside of 'Main' you might say `var enemy1:MovieClip = new Enemy`.You can then add it to the display list if you choose. Meanwhile, of course, you have a class called 'Enemy.as' that holds the code for your enemy, whatever that is. It MIGHT be a graphic MovieClip in your .fla library. If that's the situation and you don't need any or much code you could add the library enemy directly from 'Main.' Just make sure to refer to it by its AS Linkage name.

Comment: I'm almost certain I did that, but I'll give it another try.

Comment: If that doesn't solve your prob. please give specific errors.

Comment: This appears to be a problem with the import statement. The error is: Error. Definition com.grapefrukt.tutorial.supergame.enemies could not be found. I notice that in the tutorial the import statement does not have a semicolon at the end. Presumably that's just a typo, but I tried it without the semicolon and get the same result. I have commented out all the code for instantiating an Enemy object- I'm sure that code will work once I find a way to import the other file.

Comment: Here's the import statement: import com.grapefrukt.tutorial.supergame.enemies;

Comment: Hmmm... am going to try including the full directory path.

Comment: Just checked the SessionData.fdb, it has both files listed with the correct directory information. It seems clear that there is something I missed when I set the project up, will keep looking...